# Passing JSON to login.php on XAMPP returns a 405

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I'm creating a simple `fetch post` request from my `<form>` to a `login.php` file on my local server using XAMPP. The `index.html index.js login.php` files are all in the root directory.

My `index.js` is the below:

```
const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(this);

  fetch("login.php", {
    method: "post",
    body: formData
  })
    .then(response => {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(text => {
      console.log(text);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

My `index.html` is:

```
<form class="form" id="myForm" action="">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

And my `login.php` is:

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

I simply just want to log to the console the responses to check the output and test my form, however when I fill out the form I get:

> index.js:7 POST http://127.0.0.1:5501/login 405 (Method Not Allowed)

So this makes me think I need to set certain permissions on my Apache server. But I don't exactly know how to do this.

Or perhaps I'm missing something else. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You must use in fetch  "login.php" instead of "login"

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that into the code, I am using login.php and getting that error

Comment: Are index.html and login.php in the same server ?
 http://127.0.0.1:5501/index.html and  http://127.0.0.1:5501/login.php

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs?

Answer (score -1):

It work on the xampp server http://127.0.0.1/example/index.html in htdocs folder